# A reproducible example for the use of separability measures in improving selection of spectral variables

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, classification

I have been working with the tutorials in GEE on `supervised` and `unsupervised` classification, but I haven't come across any examples on the use of separability measures such as `Jeffreys-Matusita`, `transformed divergence` or `B-distance` for instance.

Here's my code to run a classification using `CART()`

```
// Add a clipping function to clip the image collection

var clipper = function(image){
  return image.clip(WG);
};

// Import raw Landsat 5 scenes and clip them over your study area
var l5filtered = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1').filterDate('2008-01-01','2012-12-31').map(clipper);

// Obtain a cloud-free composite of the scenes filtered
var cloudfree = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: l5filtered,
  asFloat: true
  });
Map.addLayer(cloudfree, {bands: ['B4','B3','B2'], max: 0.3}, 'composite');

// Specify the bands of the Landsat composite to be used as predictors (p)
var predictionBands = ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'];

// Step 2: Creating training data manually
// Draw a polygon around a bare ground area and import it as a featureCollection
// Click New property and import the new 'class' and give it a value of 0
// Similarly vegetation and water features were created

// Merging the three featureCollections to obtain a single featureCollection
var trainingFeatures = bare.merge(vegetation).merge(water);

// Note - we use .sampleRegions, if we have a featureCollection and we want to sample an image
// given a featureCollection

var classifierTraining = cloudfree.select(predictionBands)
                                  .sampleRegions({
                                    collection: trainingFeatures,
                                    properties : ['class'],
                                    scale: 30
                                  });

// Let's instantiate a CART and train it
var classifier = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
                   features: classifierTraining,
                   classProperty: 'class',
                   inputProperties: predictionBands
});

// Classify the image
var classified = cloudfree.select(predictionBands).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(classified, {min:0, max:2, palette: ['red','green','blue']}, 'classified');

// ACCURACY ASSESSMENT
// Step 1: Partition the set of known values into training and testing sets

// Adding a randomColumn of values ranging from 0 to 1
var trainingTesting = classifierTraining.randomColumn();

var trainingSet = trainingTesting.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',0.6));
var testingSet = trainingTesting.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',0.6));

// Now run the classifier only with the trainingSet
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
  features: trainingSet,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: predictionBands
});

// Now classify the testData and obtain a Confusion matrix
var confusionMatrix = ee.ConfusionMatrix(testingSet.classify(trained)
                                                   .errorMatrix({
                                                     actual: 'class',
                                                     predicted: 'classification'
                                                   }));

// Now print the ConfusionMatrix and expand the object to inspect the matrix()
// One can also obtain basic descriptive statistics from the confusionMatrix
print('Confusion matrix:', confusionMatrix);
print('Overall Accuracy:', confusionMatrix.accuracy());
print('Producers Accuracy:', confusionMatrix.producersAccuracy());
print('Consumers Accuracy:', confusionMatrix.consumersAccuracy());
```

Unsure of how to calculate separability measures. I have shared the assets necessary. Here's the code link as well - https://code.earthengine.google.com/cb156ba6f71b6448f08bf106162c6373

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted is not reproducible, so I'm starting from the classification example found in [this introductory repo](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/nclinton/EE101).

It's also not clear what you mean by the "use" of separability measures.  I'm assuming that means you use them to assess how good of a job you've done creating a training dataset.  For that reason, what you need here is training data, which is obtained through:

```
// Function to cloud mask from the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  // Return the masked image, scaled to TOA reflectance, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

// Map the function over one year of data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
    .map(maskL8sr)

var composite = collection.median();

// Display the results.
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.3});

// Get some pre-made demonstration labels.
var labels = ee.FeatureCollection('users/nclinton/demo_landcover_labels');
Map.addLayer(labels, {}, 'labels');
// print(labels.first()); // Just to check.

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];

var training = composite.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: labels, 
  properties: ['landcover'], 
  scale: 30
});
// print(training.size()) // N=98
```

That's just the first part of the classification example.  Now, to check separability of the classes, here is a whole long list of distance measures, taken mostly from [the excellent textbook by Schowengerdt](https://www.elsevier.com/books/remote-sensing/schowengerdt/978-0-12-369407-2):

```
// Compute per-class statistics.

// First, turn the prediction bands into vectors.
training = training.map(function(f) {
  // return f.set('vec', f.toArray(bands));
  return f.set('vec', f.toDictionary(bands).values(bands));
})

// Make a list of objects where each object corresponds to a class.
// Each object stores its label and a list of all the spectral
// vectors that belong to that class.
var lists = ee.List(training.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().group(0, 'class'), 
  selectors: ['landcover', 'vec']
}).get('groups'));

// Map over the lists to compute means and covariances.
// Note that the mean reducer works on arrays, and the 
// covariance reducer works on a list of 1D arrays.
lists = lists.map(function(obj) {
  var array = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(obj).get('list'));
  var list = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(obj).get('list')).map(function(l) {
    return ee.Array(l)
  });
  var mean = array.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean(), [0]);
  // Watch out with this reducer.  It is an approximate solution.
  var covariance = list.reduce(ee.Reducer.covariance());
  return ee.Dictionary(obj).combine({
    mean: mean.transpose(),
    covariance: covariance
  })
});
print(lists)

// Implement lots of distance measures.
var classes = ee.List.sequence(0, 2);

var block = classes.map(function(i) {
  return classes.map(function(j) {
    var mean_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('mean'));
    var mean_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('mean'));
    return mean_i.subtract(mean_j).reduce('sum', [0]).project([0])
  })
})
print('block', block)

var euclidean = classes.map(function(i) {
  return classes.map(function(j) {
    var mean_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('mean'));
    var mean_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('mean'));
    var diff = mean_i.subtract(mean_j).project([0]);
    return diff.dotProduct(diff).sqrt();
  })
})
print('euclidean', euclidean)

var angular = classes.map(function(i) {
  return classes.map(function(j) {
    var mean_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('mean')).project([0]);
    var mean_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('mean')).project([0]);
    return mean_i.dotProduct(mean_j)
        .divide(mean_i.dotProduct(mean_i).sqrt())
        .divide(mean_j.dotProduct(mean_j).sqrt())
        .acos()
  })
})
print('angular', angular)

var mahalanobis = classes.map(function(i) {
  return classes.map(function(j) {
    var mean_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('mean'));
    var mean_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('mean'));
    var sigma_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('covariance'));
    var sigma_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('covariance'));
    return mean_i.subtract(mean_j).transpose() // 1x6
        .matrixMultiply(sigma_i.add(sigma_j).divide(2).matrixInverse()) // 6x6
        .matrixMultiply(mean_i.subtract(mean_j))
        .sqrt()
        .get([0, 0])
  })
})
print('mahalanobis', mahalanobis)

var bhattacharyya = classes.map(function(i) {
  return classes.map(function(j) {
    var mean_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('mean'));
    var mean_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('mean'));
    var sigma_i = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(i)).get('covariance'));
    var sigma_j = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(lists.get(j)).get('covariance'));
    var mh = mean_i.subtract(mean_j).transpose()
        .matrixMultiply(sigma_i.add(sigma_j).divide(2).matrixInverse())
        .matrixMultiply(mean_i.subtract(mean_j))
        .get([0, 0])
        .sqrt();
    var t2 = sigma_i.add(sigma_j).divide(2).matrixDeterminant()
        .divide(sigma_i.matrixDeterminant().sqrt())
        .divide(sigma_j.matrixDeterminant().sqrt())
        .log()
        .divide(2);
    return mh.divide(8).add(t2)
  })
})
print('bhattacharyya', bhattacharyya)

var jm = ee.Array(bhattacharyya).multiply(-1).exp()
    .multiply(-1).add(1).multiply(2).sqrt();
print('jm', jm)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is super helpful :)

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Nicholas. But there is an error when code is executing: angular
List (Error)
Number.acos: Invalid result for input: 1.0000000000000002.